# Is it fair to compare a 2XL AWS instance to a similar setup on a rack server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, virtual-machines, physical-to-virtual

I'm trying to create an extremely basic model of what a setup in Amazon Web Services might look like translated over to an on-premises cloud. I'm aware that Amazon is quite SAN-reliant, and pretty complex, but please bear with me on this simple model :)

How do these two setups compare? Is one more powerful than the other, and is there a good rule of thumb for equivalence?

```
AWS: m3.2xlarge has 8 vCPUs at 2.1GHz, 30GiB RAM, and 2x80 SSD drives.
Physical Rack Server: 8 physical CPUs at 2.2GHz, 32GB RAM, 500GB hard drive.
```

Ideally I'd love to know something like "one AWS instance like this is roughly half as powerful as the physical version."

Comment: There are far too many variable in play here. Just deploy an instance and benchmark your software on it. Should only cost a few bucks, and you'll get much better data out of that process than by asking here.

Comment: Yeah, I thought someone might say that. This is for a back-of-the-envelope calculation, and I unfortunately can't benchmark at this point due to the workplace environment.

Comment: Well then really the best I can say is that yes, these two are roughly equivalent, *for some unspecified and ambiguous workload*. At first, you might think that the disk on the EC2 instance type would out-perform the non-SSD disk of the physical server, but even that is highly dependent on the type of IO. For highly-sequential workloads, spinning disk will usually trounce all over SSDs.

Comment: Haha, definitely – I appreciate you humoring me with this. In a software development setting I'd want to run those first, but this is just for a research project :)